Error at *end* of code pasted into Spyder console, all *preceding* objects missing
I am trying this code for clustering, adapted as follows:
import os
os.chdir("C:/path/to/working/directory")
import numpy as np
Dist = np.load('20240612.1201_Dist.npz')['Dist'] # Load distance matrix
Dist.shape # 30,011 x 30,011 # Check that matrix shape is square
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata
t=3 # The maximum distance
y_pred = fclusterdata(Dist.T, t, criterion='distance')
   # Used transpose to convert lower triangular data to upper triangular
# import datetime as dt # Unfortunately, this was missing !!!!!!

# Where the error occurred
print( dt.datetime.now(), ": Finished ",
       os.path.basename(__file__), sep='' )

The problem is that I copied and pasted the code snippet from a text file into the Spyder console, so I was missing an import datetime as dt.  It is used at the end of the code to print the completion time, and since I noted the start time, I could determine how long it took.
When I pasted code into the Spyder console, the Windows Task Manager showed the Python process churning away.  Since I had to leave, I left the process running.  When I came in the morning, I saw the error from the missing datetime module:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[1], line 12
    print( dt.datetime.now(), ": Finished ",
NameError: name 'dt' is not defined

I was disappointed to find that all of the objects occurring before the erroneous code were not shown in Spyder's Variable Explorer, e.g., t, y_pred.  They exist in the namespace and also show up with dir():
>>> t
Out[3]: 3

>>> y_pred
Out[4]: array([ 4184, 29948,  4185, ..., 20769, 20751, 20752], dtype=int32)

>>> dir()
Out[5]:
['Dist',
 <...snip...>
 't',
 'y_pred']

Clicking Refresh on the Variable Explorer doesn't change anything.  Is there any way to force Spyder to reacquire the contents of the Variable Explorer?
I am using Spyder 5.4.3 from Anaconda on Windows 10.
Afternote: Not even simple things like t=t, x=t, and x=5 cause the Variable Explorer to change.  This was not a problem before the error.

Based on this answer, I tried toggling some of the checkboxes under Tools > Preferences > Variable explorer.  This "woke" the Variable Explorer up.  Not only did it display new variables, but it showed them updated when they are assigned with new values.
While I cite a Q&A with similar symptoms, the circumstances differ.
